# How to subtract fields and insert the value in other field automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, field, subtraction

I need to create a table with two fields that has values and a third field that takes the values and subtract them in the total field.

i need a query something like that if it exist.

create table calculation (id int(11),val1 int(11),val2-val1 int(11) as total);

```
id    val1    val2     total
1      5       4         1
```

Comment: creating table can't have such operations - or +, you need to create table with 3 fields, and do the calculations in the INSERT statement

Comment: @Yazan This is not best practice! Read about views, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not store data that can be easily calculated on the fly. I'd recommend you use a `VIEW` instead of a `TABLE`. Read more about views [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html).

```
CREATE VIEW my_first_view AS
SELECT
id, val1, val2, val1 - val2 AS total
FROM your_table;
```

This way you don't store redundant data, but can use the view as if it were a normal table. If it's a simple query like above, the view can even be updatable and insertable. Read more about this special case [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-updatability.html).

```
SELECT * FROM my_first_view;
```

will give you the result you want.

Comment: yes, i did not think about views, as it may not be part of the scope, but sure, if @moussa houssein can use views, he should go with your sol. :)